# Add IO functionality to imperative language parser

Tags: haskell, parser-combinators

I'm trying to add IO functionality such as `read` and `write` statements to a parser for an imperative language like shown here https://wiki.haskell.org/Parsing_a_simple_imperative_language

I want to add statements such as `write "example"` which will write "example" to stdout with something like `putStrLn` or `print`.

So far I've made the following changes

```
-- Add Write data type so that a statement such as `write "test"` can be represented as a statement
data Stmt = Seq [Stmt]
          | ... (same as before)
          | Write String
            deriving (Show)

-- write needs to be added to reservedNames as it has a function in the language
languageDef =
  emptyDef { Token...
           , ...
           , Token.reservedNames  = [ "if"
                                    , ...
                                    , "write"
                                    ...

-- whenever a statement is parsed, writeStmt function now needs to be called to parse a write statement
statement' :: Parser Stmt
statement' =  ifStmt
          <|> whileStmt
          <|> skipStmt
          <|> assignStmt
          <|> writeStmt

-- do reserved write, get the identifier, print it to stdout and return the Write statement
writeStmt :: Parser Stmt
writeStmt =
  do reserved "write"
    var <- identifier
    print var
    return $ Write var
```

I'm getting errors on `var <- identifier` in `whileStmt` and i'm not sure what else needs to be added or changed to get this to work. thanks

Comment: The indentation looks wrong at the end. `var` should be as indented as `reserved` and so must be the other lines below. I am also not sure about the `print var` line, that looks weird: we are parsing the code, not executing it at this stage.

Comment: The parser shouldn't be printing anything; it just has to produce a correct `Write` value. It's the job of your *evaluator* to process a `Write` value into a call to `print` or the like.

Comment: Something like `writeStmt = do { reserved "write"; Write <$> identifier }`.

Answer (score 0):

As was noted in the comments, you need to fix the indentation so all of the statements in your `do`-block line up:

```
writeStmt :: Parser Stmt
writeStmt =
  do reserved "write"
     var <- identifier
     print var
     return $ Write var
```

and then, you need to delete that `print var` statement.  During *parsing*, you just want to identify write statements and store them in your abstract syntax tree (AST) (i.e., in your `Stmt` tree).  The actual printing will take place in a separate function that executes the program represented by the AST.

Unfortunately, the wiki page you're working from only shows you how to perform the parsing, not how to actually execute the parsed representation.